# Tweet something based on JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I have my Codepen which can be found here (https://codepen.io/Mortiferr/pen/repRgX)

I have a button like so:

```
<button onclick ="tweetIt()" class="twitter" href="#twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i> Tweet Quote</button>
```

It is a random quote machine that generates a random quote from an API. I want to make it so that the user can tweet out the quote on the screen. I have a variable called `quote` and `author` so I need to somehow use those to send out the tweet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

```
$('.twitter').on('click', function() {
  makeTwitterPage('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + encodeURIComponent('"' + quote + '" ' + author));
});
function makeTwitterPage(url){
  window.open(url, 'Share', 'width=700, height=500, toolbar=0, scrollbars=1 ,location=0 ,statusbar=0,menubar=0, resizable=1');
}
```